# Importing csv from a subdirectory in Python

Tags: python

My project has a bunch of csv files that may or may not be called based on user input. I'd like to store these files in a subdirectory to keep my project folder uncluttered. I'm utterly confused as to how to do this. Most of the resources I've dug up involve importing a module or package from a subdirectory rather than a basic data file.

The line of code that imports my csv currently looks like:

```
target_doc = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
```

I'm assuming a solution will involve setting up a path variable, using import os and import sys, and perhaps splitting this line multiple parts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open files by file path. Just use `open('/path/to/file')`.

Importing is only necessary for modules and packages - Python source code.

The only real notes here are to use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) where joining paths for good compatibility across different operating systems and filesystems. The rest of the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module is also worth a look wherever files are involved. Another common trap with windows paths is that using backslashes escape characters, so you must escape your backslashes (`"some\\file"`) - an ugly option, use raw strings (`r"some\file"`), use forward slashes (Python will actually handle this automatically), or - the best option, pass your path as arguments to the aforementioned `os.path.join()`.

It may also be worth noting that using [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) would improve your code.

e.g:

```
with open(os.path.join("path", "to", "file.csv"), 'rU') as file:
    target_doc = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
    ...
```

Using `with` ensures your file gets closed - even if exceptions occur.

Comment: Oh wow yea that was simple. Thanks for the _with_ statement suggestion, hadn't seen it used this way before.

Comment: Implementing the with statement causes an I/O error when I try to write the file into an array:
 for row in target_doc:
     target_list.extend(row)

Comment: @acpigeon ``csv.reader()`` iterates over the file as you use it - so you need any statements that use it to be inside the ``with`` block, otherwise the file will be closed. Note you could accomplish what you are trying to do there by just doing ``list(csv.reader(...))`` (the same is true of any iterator you wish to make a list from, and if you want to make a list while making minor changes or filtering it, check out [list comprehensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY)).

Comment: Actually, I misspeak, if you are using ``extend()``, then you would need to use [``itertools.chain.from_iterable()``](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to get the same result, although normally when reading from a CSV file, this is less useful than having a list of lists.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the help. I'm using append() in this case but good to note.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import os
cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__) # get current location of script
```

And then use os.path.join(cwd, 'some/../path') to construct absolute paths to any location you like; so your paths are only relative to your script location, regardless of the current working directory for python interpretor.
Mai also use os.sep if you don't want to depend on unix's '/'-convention.

Comment: Wouldn't it be less trouble to use a relative path rather than an absolute one? We know from the question that the default directory is OK.

Comment: You might be right, I think I didn't exactly get the question.

Comment: FYI, this one will bite you if the code is within a module built with setuptools

Answer (score 1):

You are on the wrong path.  Python path and import are only for "linking" other python code into your system.  Other files used as resources by your system are accessed by specifying the full path of the file:

```
 target_doc = csv.reader(open('/resources/csv_files/sample.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
```

or a relative path from where you're running the python file:

```
 target_doc = csv.reader(open('csv_files/sample.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use :

path_in = '/directory_whatever_it_is/sample_data.csv'

sample_data = pd.read_csv(path_in)

Comment: _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.